# Unity Terrein Tree Painter paints under the level

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I made a tree in blender and Imported in unity as fbx (all of it's objects were merged). I started to paint them on my terrain, but half of my tree was under the terrain and only the leaf were on the ground (which made it look like a bush). What should I do?

Comment: could it be that the trees origin isnt at the right position?

Comment: how can I fix that? @nka_Zz

Comment: your origin should be at the root of your trees. You can move your Tree in Blender so that the root is at the origin mostly at the center of the trunk so that the placement is even.

Comment: got everything figured out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to the originpoint of your object, the unity terrain tool will place the object originpoint on the point you clicked on. If the point of the object is in the middle and not at the bottom of the object, half of the object will be underground.

Open the file in Blender and move your object so that the origin is at the roots of the tree (or to the designated point you want unity to place your object on the terrain).